# My second for loop is not running?

Tags: java, loops

I have 2 for loops, I am working on a 2048 like game. This method returns true if something slid to the left. However, it returns false to me and only "banana" is printing, which means the other for loop isn't even executed. What could be the case?

```
  public boolean slideLeft(int[][] array, int row) {
    int[] array2 = new int[array.length];
    boolean result = false;
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      array2[j] = array[j][row];
      System.out.println("banana");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <array2.length; i ++) {
      if (array2[i] == 0 && array2[i+1] != 0 && i != array2.length-1) {
        System.out.println("apple");
        array2[i] = array2 [i+1];
        result = true;
      }
      if(array2[i] != 0 && i != 0 && array2[i-1] == array2[i]) {
        System.out.println("pear");
        array2[i-1] = 2*(array2[i-1]);
        array2[i]=0;
        result = true;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Or your other loop is running but none of your conditions is met. What exactly are your conditions supposed to test?

Comment: Fire up your debugger and go to step-by-step execution.  You can inspect every variable and find out what's going on.

Comment: Or, create `else` in your both `if` and put some printing there, like `System.out.println("not an apple");`.

Answer (score 0):

Second `for` loop executed but none of condition inside the second `for` loop is not match. Then you will not get any out put.

You can make sure second `for` loop is running just put a `else` and print something.

You need to reconsider and rethink about condition inside the second `for` loop to correct them.

Answer (score 0):

Your other for loop would throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `i==array2.length-1`, because the following condition is evaluated from left to right, so `array2[i+1]` would be aveluated before `i != array2.length-1` is evaluated.

```
  if (array2[i] == 0 && array2[i+1] != 0 && i != array2.length-1) {
    System.out.println("apple");
    array2[i] = array2 [i+1];
    result = true;
  }
```

You should change it to :

```
  if ( i != array2.length-1 & array2[i] == 0 && array2[i+1] != 0) {
    System.out.println("apple");
    array2[i] = array2 [i+1];
    result = true;
  }
```

Your second if condition avoids a similar exception, since you check that `i != 0` before checking that `array2[i-1] == array2[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that you are trying to create an array, `array2`, of integers of length `array.length`. There is a possibility that the `array.length` could just contain two rows (possibility of single row is eliminated because if there was just one row you would have seen `IndexOutofBoundException`) in such case your `if conditions` will never get executed.

A way you can work through is by placing `check statements for array.length` and `else` clause in the second `for loop`.